# How to remove the shadow created by bottom sheet dialog fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I have created a modal bottom sheet dialog fragment but it covers the full screen with the shadow or transparent black color when it expands.

How do I remove that shadow from the bottom-sheet fragment?

Comment: Can you mark the answer accepted if it works

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 12):

Try my code below:

**1. Create a bottom sheet style in style.xml**

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0</item>
</style>
```

**2. Add your style to onCreate function on your BottomSheetDialogFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
}
```

Hope that help :)